# Is it possible to update flatpaks with the "Software Updater"?

Tags: updates, update-manager, flatpak

Currently, when I want to update my flatpaks I have to open the gnome software center and look for updates there. My other software (apt, snaps) are updated by the "Software Updater", aka `update-manager`. Is it possible to also update flatpaks via the Software Updater?

Comment: You can do so using the Flatpak Software Store, or the terminal

Comment: @TheCoolMan I know how to update my flatpaks. But can I configure the Software Updater so that it also updates my flatpaks? So that I don't have to deal with them separately.

Comment: I don't think so, the Software Updater is a GNOME/Ubuntu app, and it doesn't offer the option to check/update for flatpaks. If the Software Updater is open-source, which is probably the case since linux apps are usually open source, you could build your own version which includes flatpaks. I have done something simmilar, so you should be able to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: `update-manager` currently handles only deb packages.

It is an Open Source application, so any community member can fork the code and/or can contribute additional features.

A proper Flatpak/Flathub (and Snapd) install already includes automatic updates, so it's understandable why perhaps there hasn't been a lot of community interest in contributing this feature to `update-manager`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that flatpaks will update automatically.

Comment: What's a "proper Flatpak install"? B/c mine is not updating flatpak/flathub packages automatically.

Comment: @xebeche see https://askubuntu.com/a/1437557/19626 for an example.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 22.04 Flatpak's "Software" store (basically a Flatpak-only version of the snap/deb-focused Ubuntu Software store) provides an interface for configuring automatic updates, and they are enabled by default.

To configure automatic updates:

1. Open the 'Software' app
   [image: Ubuntu search for Software app]
2. Select the triple horizontal bars button in the upper right corner.
   [image: dropdown menu]
3. Configure Update Preferences as you please. Here I disabled automatic updates since I prefer to manually update my apps for sake of stability and time management.
   [image: update preferences dialog]